# Changing video source to image source when hover/ mouseover html

Tags: html, jquery, flexbox, src, onmouseover

So I have video thumbnails in a flexbox. How can I change it to display an image when hovered on the video?
I can change video to video, image to image, however am not sure how to change the source from video to image, and as it is in a flexbox I can't hide the image under the video

```
<video autoplay loop muted src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4 id="video""  
             onmouseout="this.src='./video.mp4'"
             onmouseover="this.src='./image.png'">  </video>
```

I also tried jQuery to replace the whole video source block, but I don't think I got it right

```
$("#video").mouseover( function () {
    var $image =  $("img").attr('src', './image.png'); 
    $(this).replaceWith($image );
     });
```

https://codepen.io/saltykiam/pen/abmGbWK

edit: how can i make an image overlay on a video

Comment: Maybe add a wrapper around the video/img tag and switch between the two on mouse over.

Comment: Do you want to show the image into an overlay or just replace the video tag with img?

Comment: @OnkarSingh show an image overlay, so when you stop hovering, the image turns back into a video

Comment: try the "poster" attribute of the video element. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea of how you can add the image into the overlay and show once someone hove the video, I hope you looking for the same

```css
.videoWraper{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
.img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0;
}
video#video {
    width: 100%;
}
.videoWraper:hover .img-overlay{
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWraper">
<video autoplay loop muted src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video">  </video>
<img class="img-overlay" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

Comment: ah yes I didn't think about that! Thank you so so much! 